# Geocoding 150 million addresses

Tags: bigdata, geocoding

I have about 150 million US street addresses that I need lat long coordinates for. I need the coordinates to be rooftop accurate. Speed isn't important, but it needs to terminate eventually, so APIs with daily limits in the 1000s (or even 100,000s) won't work. I have a basically infinite budget. I want to show the points on a non-Google map, which violates the Google Maps API TOS, so Google is out. Is there any tool with which I can do this?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/openaddresses/wiki/RESTService could be one of your options.

Comment: Looks like openaddresses.org doesn't exist anymore, or at least not in the form described in the wiki. Requests to the API 404.

Comment: http://www.programmableweb.com/news/7-free-geocoding-apis-google-bing-yahoo-and-mapquest/2012/06/21

Comment: @approxiblue I looked into each of the APIs listed on the page, and each had some fatal flaw except for MapQuest, which looks promising so far. I'm waiting to hear back from the rep I emailed. I'll update when I find out if it'll work.

Comment: No Web-based API will work for this volume of data, since it will take months to complete. You need an off-line solution, such as http://www.YAddress.net (made by the company I work for).